# why there is no $app->request->delete() in slim framework?

Tags: rest, slim

I develop API with slim framework. I know there is no request parameter for `delete` like her friends (`put`, `get`, `post`).

```
$token = $app->request->get('token');
$token = $app->request->post('token');
$token = $app->request->put('token');
```

When i take parameter in `delete`, i always use get to take the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using an old version of Slim? The method is definitely available: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Http/Request.php#L308